# Is it possible to obtain the address of the 'this' pointer?

Tags: c++, reference, this, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I read that `this` is an rvalue and we cannot get its address by applying `&this`.

In my code, I have tried to use a reference binding to `this`. I'm wondering which way will give the address of `this`? Or are both wrong?

What exactly is `this`? An lvalue, an rvalue, a keyword, or something else?

```
void MyString::test_this() const{
    std::cout << "this: " << this << std::endl;
    const MyString * const& this_ref = this;
    std::cout << "thie_ref: " << &this_ref << std::endl;
    const MyString * const&& this_right = this;
    std::cout << "thie_right: " << &this_right << std::endl;
}

//this: 00CFFC14
//thie_ref: 00CFFB14
//thie_right: 00CFFAFC
```

Comment: `&this_ref ` : you're printing the address **of the pointer**, not the address **stored in the pointer**

Comment: @DavidHaim to be clear, that's not just a pointer; it's a *reference* to a pointer. I.e. `const MyString * const& this_ref`. Taking it's address should result in the address of the pointer being referenced. The OP is trying (for utterly inexplicable reasons) to acquire `&this`.

Comment: What is the point of knowing the adress of "this" pointer ? I feel like this is an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) . What are you really trying to do ?

Comment: I mean I know it's wrong to write &this, thus I wonder if there is any way to get the address. "this" is declared as Classname * const this, and I'm trying to use it as a common pointer.

Comment: Just in passing, `this` is not unique in this regard. You also can't take the address of a variable that's marked `register`.

Comment: Note that if you attempt to do exactly the same thing again in the same function block, like `const MyString * const& my_ref2 = this;` you'll also get a different pointer value.

Comment: There is no such thing as '*the* address of *the* `this` pointer'. Every distinct method invocation will have its own.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I'm wondering which may give the address of `this`? Or both are wrong?

Neither is the address of `this`, because the C++ abstract machine doesn't define an address for it. `this` is like `0`. You can't get the address of 0, it's not an entity with storage, just some value. So what does this do?

```
int const& i = 0;
```

It creates a temporary object, initializes it with 0, and then binds the reference to it. The same exact thing occurs in your code. You create references to different temporary objects that hold the *value* of `this`.

`this` is a keyword that stands for the address of the object that the member function is being executed for. The C++ abstract machine doesn't require it to occupy storage, so it's always (logically) just a plain value, like 0.

There's merit to not requiring `this` to occupy storage. It allows C++ to be implemented over an ABI where `this` is passed in a register (something that isn't addressable normally). If `&this` had to be well-defined, i.e. if `this` had to be addressable, it would preclude an implementation from using a register for passing the address. The C++ standard generally aims not to tie implementations up like that.

Comment: _"if `this` had to be addressable, it would preclude an implementation from using a register for passing the address"_ Only if it were odr-used, though, right? By as-if, the compiler already skips storage for loads of things during "optimisation"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes. But the issue as I see it, is that the ABI would have to be determined by the body of the member function (since that's what may or may not odr-use `this`). While on the other hand, calling code (moreover, the header) usually has no knowledge about the function body. In such a state of affairs I'd wager implementations will choose a pessimistic ABI. I could be over-simplifying and so way off the mark, though.

Comment: So this_ref and this_right just copy the address of the object "this" points, and &this_ref and &this_right just return the two pointers' address,right?

Comment: @RangeHao - Yes. Neither pointer whose address you are viewing is actually `this`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is correct:: If `&this` was needed, the callee could just spill it from a register to a stack location, like if you take the address of any other arg.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/PkoQ-i for x86-64 System V shows gcc and clang taking the address of a function arg with `int *volatile p = &x;`  (gcc decides not to actually spill `x` itself to memory, just to store `p =` the address of the stack slot where it would have spilled `x` if it had been used.)

Comment: The caller doesn't need to know what address the callee chooses to put the pointer-to-`this` in, so we can leave that to the callee.  C++ doesn't have any way for the callee to change where the caller thinks the object is stored; that doesn't make any sense for automatic or static storage where the object's location is part of the stack layout (for example) or globals.  And `ptr->method()` doesn't give `method()` access to `ptr`, just to a *copy* of `ptr`.  So reading `&this` wouldn't give you the caller's `&ptr`, even if `&this` was something you could do.

Comment: So really `this` is more like `register T *const this` - you can't take its address, and you can't modify it.  It's also not allowed to be `nullptr`, so checks like `if(this == nullptr)` can optimize away: don't use that for recursive traversal of trees / linked lists.  Other than that, it's pretty much like a hidden extra arg to a method, and that's exactly how most ABIs implement it.

Answer (score 8):

What is meant by "you cannot take the address of `this`" is, that you cannot write `&this`.

You are asking for the address *represented* by the `this` pointer, right? This is, what your first output does.

`this` itself is not materialized as a pointer, like e.g. `MyString* x` would be. Here, `x` itself has a location in memory and you can do sth. like `&x`. This is not possible for `this`.

The answer to your last question is: yes, `this` is a keyword. The expression `this` is a primary expression. You can read about it in Section `[expr.prim.this]` of the C++ standard.

Comment: In most cases (for non-virtual functions) you can think of `this` as syntactic sugar for an extra arg holding a pointer to the object.  But it's not allowed to be `nullptr`, so a recursive linked-list or tree traversal that checks `if (this == nullptr) return;` as the termination condition is broken: that check can optimize away. And as you point out, `this` can't have its address taken, so even without the help of the as-if rule, it can be kept in a register in a C++ implementation on a "normal" CPU. Other objects often don't actually have addresses if the C++ source never takes their address

Answer (score 6):

`this` is a pointer containing the address to the `current object`. It is not a variable that is stored somewhere (or could even be changed), it is a special keyword with special properties.

If you want to know the address of the "current object" you can simply output as shown below in the program:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
            void fun()
            {
                    cout << "Address of this :: " << this << endl;
                    void *ptr = this;
                    cout << "Addrss of ptr :: " << ptr << endl;
            }
 };

 int main()
 {
    Test obj;

    cout << "Address of obj :: " << &obj << endl;

    obj.fun();

    return 0;
 }
```

Above program produces below output:

> Address of obj :: 0x7fffef913627
>
> Address of this :: 0x7fffef913627
>
> Addrss of ptr :: 0x7fffef913627

I hope it helps!

Comment: Btw, your are printing the value of ptr (the address stored within ptr), not the address of ptr, that would be `&ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword behaves essentially as `&__self` where `__self` is a lvalue designating the object on which the member function is run (the `*this` object) except that an overloaded `operator&()` isn't used.

So `&this` would mean `&&__self` which obviously doesn't make sense, you can't take the address of an address, just like you can't take the address of a scalar return value of a function:

```
int fi(); 
int *fpi();
```

Both `&(fi())` and `&(fpi())` are illegal as the rvalue returned is a scalar (probably stored in a register) and **as a pure scalar value does not have an address**.